# Implementing cost in time calculations. How?

Tags: php

I have the following function that adds the times contained in an array. It doesn't return the pay out. I would like to return the `totalTime` AND the `totalPayOut`.

Like so:

```
function sumTimesInArray($times = []) {
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(":", $time);
        $seconds += $hour * 3600;
        $seconds += $minute * 60;
        $seconds += $second;
    }
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
    return sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}

$times = ["01:00:00","00:15:00","00:00:30",]; // = 01:15:30 hours

$pay = 10;

$totalTime = sumTimesInArray($times);

print($totalTime);
```

Given a `pay` of $10/hour, how would I implement this so that it includes the prorated pay for fractional hours? Currently working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the `DateTime` and `DateIntervall` class ([Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)). It can sum times and parse them for you, so you do not have to do it yourself.

But you can also easy modify your code:

```
function sumTimesAndCalcPay($times = [], $payPerHour = 1) {
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(":", $time);
        $seconds += $hour * 3600;
        $seconds += $minute * 60;
        $seconds += $second;
    }
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
    $time = sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    $pay = $payPerHour * ($hours + $minutes/60 + $seconds/3600);
    return [$time, $pay];
}

$times = ["01:00:00","00:15:00","00:00:30",]; // = 01:15:30 hours

$pay = 10;

[$totalTime, $totalPay] = sumTimesAndCalcPay($times, $pay);

print($totalTime);
print($totalPay);
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the code i have tried, you can try

Syntax PHP

```
<?php 
function sumTimesInArray($pay, $times) {
        
    $dataPayouts = array();
    $payoutTotal = 0;
    $totalSeconds = 0; // not reset
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(":", $time);
        $seconds = 0; // reset
        $seconds += $hour * 3600;
        $seconds += $minute * 60;
        $seconds += $second;
        $totalSeconds += $seconds;
        
        $itemPayout = ($pay / 3600) * $seconds;
        $dataPayouts[] = array(
                           'time' => $time,
                           'pay_per_hour' => $pay,
                           'item_payout' => $itemPayout
                         );

        $payoutTotal += $itemPayout;
    }

    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
    
    $resume = array(
        'hour_total' => gmdate("H:i:s", $totalSeconds),
        'payout_total' => $payoutTotal,
        'details' => $dataPayouts
    );
    return $resume;
}

$times = array("01:00:00","00:15:00","00:00:30",); // = 01:15:30 hours
$pay = 10;
echo json_encode(sumTimesInArray($pay, $times));
```

Result JSON

```
{
  "hour_total": "01:15:30",
  "payout_total": 12.583333333333,
  "details": [
    {
      "time": "01:00:00",
      "pay_per_hour": 10,
      "item_payout": 10
    },
    {
      "time": "00:15:00",
      "pay_per_hour": 10,
      "item_payout": 2.5
    },
    {
      "time": "00:00:30",
      "pay_per_hour": 10,
      "item_payout": 0.083333333333333
    }
  ]
}
```

Demo code : http://codepad.org/z9x3Hsna